# SystemJS not loading modules from node_modules

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I'm using SystemJS to load a simple JavaScript file:

```
define("main", ["require", "exports", "jquery"], function (require, exports, $) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    console.log($(document).html());
});
```

I'm loading it like so:

```
<script>require("systemjs")</script>
<script>
    SystemJS.import('./dist/app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

But I am getting an error when I run it in electron:

`GET file:///D:/Projects/myapp/app/jquery net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Why is SystemJS not looking for jquery in `node_modules` like any other sane javascript loader? How do I get it to look there?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that my compiler hadn't detected the changes yet so the generated file contained code for a different module. It still isn't working the way I want it too, but at least it's not erroring :/